# Why cant I chose the HTTP Conn Type in Airflow?

Tags: python, http, airflow

I have created a virtual env in Python named `landbox`. Inside that virtual env I have installed the HTTP provider by doing a pip: `pip install apache-airflow-providers-http==2.0.0`.

So to check which providers are installed I did: `airflow providers list`. That gave me the following output:

```
/home/airflow/landbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:241: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
  if StrictVersion(sqlite3.sqlite_version) < StrictVersion(min_sqlite_version):
package_name                    | description                                                                 | version
================================+=============================================================================+========
apache-airflow-providers-ftp    | File Transfer Protocol (FTP) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc114             | 1.1.0  
apache-airflow-providers-http   | Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) https://www.w3.org/Protocols/            | 2.0.2  
apache-airflow-providers-imap   | Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501 | 1.0.1  
apache-airflow-providers-sqlite | SQLite https://www.sqlite.org/                                              | 1.0.2
```

As you can see the HTTP provider seems to be installed. However, when I try to add an HTTP connection in the Airflow UI I dont see the HTTP option under `Conn Type`.

[enter image description here]

[image: 2]

I dont understand what is going wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: @OlafKock I have edited my question.

Comment: The list of Connection types is also created internally from all installed providers. Is your webserver running in the same virtual environment?

Comment: Ha Bas (landgenoot, Ik ben ook Nederlands). How can I check that?

Comment: @BasHarenslak can I expect an answer from you?

Comment: It depends on how you're running Airflow. Are you starting Airflow as `airflow webserver` (with your virtualenv `landbox` activated)? Or running in Docker containers? Or something else? You have to ensure the environment that the webserver is running in, has the `apache-airflow-providers-http` package installed.

Comment: @BasHarenslak I'm running Airflow as a webserver with my virtualenv `landbox` activated. I run this command in my VSC terminal: airflow scheduler.